# docx4j inside JBoss NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jboss, docx4j

I get following error when executing on jboss :

`WordprocessingMLPackage template = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .load(new FileInputStream(new File(name)));`

- Java version: 1.7.0_25
- JBoss version: 7.1.1.Final
- docx4j version:
  2.8.1

Error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.docx4j.jaxb.Context`

I know there is already a question regarding this issue, but no answer was given and seems like the question was left behind.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my new answer at [Cannot use docx4j inside of JBoss 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204635/cannot-use-docx4j-inside-of-jboss-7/19371440#19371440)

My test used same version of JBoss (7.1.1) but:

- old Java (1.6.0_27)
- newer docx4j (current nightly)

I don't think those differences should matter though.

With this config, it is safe to ignore the log message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper

Comment: So can we ignore it completely ? +1 to everyone talking about this :)