# Docx4j on Jboss 6.3

Tags: jaxb, jboss6.x, docx4j

I get this error:

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/docx4j/jaxb/NamespacePrefixMapperSunInternal (Module "deployment.NetiEar.ear.NetiWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.getPrefixMapper(NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.java:58) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.(Context.java:103) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:679) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.get(Load3.java:132) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:454) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:371) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:262) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:242) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:158) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at it.led.neti.componenti.stampa.servlet.GestioneStampaServlet.submit(GestioneStampaServlet.java:466) [classes:]
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/internal/bind/marshaller/NamespacePrefixMapper
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper from [Module "deployment.NetiEar.ear.NetiWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 50 more

The class is where it should be. 
I've included the jar file in the build path. 
What's wrong? Please give me some help.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301422/1031689 or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/25471962/1031689

Those links describe how to define and use a suitable JBoss module.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but nothing seems changed after editing all the stuff. I still have problems related to link to resources. Do you have any other suggestion?